# Query to Method Expression in Linq!

Tags: linq

How can i right this in method Expression!

> var query =
>       from l in list where l.Key == "M"
>
> select new { Value = l, Length = l.Length };

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to turn it into a sequence of extension method calls?

```
var query = list.Where(l => l.Key == "M")
                .Select(l => new { Value = l, Length = l.Length });
```

Comment: fast typing. glad I refreshed before posting mine. Feel stupid when someone has same answer but ahead of me.